# Cannot request data using fetch (JS) from Django REST Framework API

Tags: django, reactjs, rest, cors, fetch

I am trying to send a POST request to my Django REST Framework API at localhost:8000. I receive the Django response when Postman sends the request, but I receive a console error on my React.js application using the fetch() function. I see that, for the React.js app's request, an OPTIONS request is sent to the Django backend.
This is the error I receive on the React app.

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/api/admin/login/' from origin 'http://ucla.localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Here is my JavaScript code.

```
fetch(authenticateUrl, {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',//"http://localhost:8000",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
      signal: abortLoginController.signal
    })
```

Here is my Django settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django_hosts.middleware.HostsRequestMiddleware',
    #'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_hosts.middleware.HostsResponseMiddleware',
]
...
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
# CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
#     'http://sub.localhost:3000',
#     'http://localhost:3000'
# )
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
```

Answer (score 0):

From what is, it seems that your request header includes a field that is not allowed by the CORS policy you setup and specifically, the field 'access-control-allow-origin' is forbidden by the policy and so your request is totally blocked. You can try either:

- To modify the CORS policy to allow that header
  or
- Setup the Django app to not send this header on your requests.